# Why index is not creating in elasticsearch 8.3.2 automatically

Tags: python, elasticsearch

- i m using Python api to insert and fetch from elasticsearch, verseion is 8.3.2
- `data = [ { 'id': 1, 'Title': 'Live1'},{ 'id': 2, 'Title': 'Live2'},{ 'id': 3, 'Title': 'Live3'}]`
- when try inserting I got Not Found error, It was working in version 7

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch("http://user:password@localhost:9200")

for e in data:
    client.index(index="movie_data", document=e, id=e['id'])
```

Error > `NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', "no such index [movie_data] and [action.auto_create_index] ([.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*]) doesn't match")`

In my yaml file i have added this `action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*`

- My related question is when i tried `client.indices.get_mapping( 'movie_data' )`

I got error > `TypeError: Positional arguments can't be used with Elasticsearch API methods. Instead only use keyword arguments.`

Comment: you can access kibana dev tools and execute command GET _cat/indices?

Comment: @rabbitbr dont have kibana, using python for querying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `action.auto_create_index` list you don't have `movie_data` so the index cannot be auto-created.

You can either add it or remove that line completely.

Comment: can you let me know what is `action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*` will do, as from blog while installing it is suggested like that, Any doc i could refer for this also will help

Comment: If you list index name patterns in that setting, it will only allow those indexes to be created automatically by ES if they don't exist. Since `movie_data` is not listed, it's not getting created when you index the first document. You can, however, [create it manually](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create) and then run your indexing code.